# How to recompile with -fPIC

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, ffmpeg, fpic

I was trying to reinstall my ffmpeg, following this [guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide), on my ARM Ubuntu machine. Unfortunately, when I compile a program which uses this lib I get the following failure:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(amrnbdec.o): relocation R_ARM_MOVW_ABS_NC against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now I would like to recompile it with `-fPIC` like the compiler is suggesting but I have no idea how. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Briefly, the error means that you *can't use a static library to be linked w/ a dynamic one*.
The correct way is to have a `libavcodec` compiled into a `.so` instead of `.a`, so the other `.so` library you are trying to build will link well.

The shortest way to do so is to add `--enable-shared` at `./configure` options. Or even you may try to disable shared (or static) libraries at all... you choose what is suitable for you!

Comment: You just saved me from a severe headache with `--enable-shared`. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this! I also want to add that I also had to do `make distclean` when re-running make to get rid of some files that had already been compiled in a static manner.

Answer (score 28):

Have a look at [this page.](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:AMD64/Fixing_-fPIC_Errors_Guide)

you can try globally adding the flag using: `export CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -fPIC"`

Comment: This fixed a node package installer (for node-swipl) that was using node-gyp and had been producing the same error. Thanks :)

Comment: I added a replacement for the dead link into archive.org

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem when building FFMPEG static libraries (e.g. libavcodec.a) for Android x86_64 target platform (using Android NDK clang). When statically linking with my library the problem occured although all FFMPEG C -> object files (*.o) were compiled with -fPIC compile option:

```
x86_64/libavcodec.a(h264_qpel_10bit.o): 
requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'ff_pw_1023' 
which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
```

The problem occured only for libavcodec.a and libswscale.a.

Source of this problem is that **FFMPEG has assembler optimizations for x86* platforms** e.g. the reported problem cause is in **libavcodec/h264_qpel_10bit.asm** -> h264_qpel_10bit.o.

When producing X86-64 bit static library (e.g. libavcodec.a) it looks like assembler files (e.g. libavcodec/h264_qpel_10bit.asm) **uses some x86 (32bit) assembler commands which are incompatible when statically linking with x86-64 bit target library** since they don't support required relocation type.

**Possible solutions**:

1. compile all ffmpeg files with no assembler optimizations (for ffmpeg this is configure option: --disable-asm)
2. produce dynamic libraries (e.g. libavcodec.so) and link them in your final library dynamically

I chose 1) and it solved the problem.

Reference: https://tecnocode.co.uk/2014/10/01/dynamic-relocs-runtime-overflows-and-fpic/

Answer (score 7):

After the configure step you probably have a makefile. Inside this makefile look for CFLAGS (or similar). puf -fPIC at the end and run make again. In other words -fPIC is a compiler option that has to be passed to the compiler somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

If you're building a shared library but need to link with **static libavcodec** add linker flags:

```
-Wl,-Bsymbolic
```

In case of cmake:

```
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-Bsymbolic")
```

Answer (score 1):

I hit this same issue trying to install Dashcast on Centos 7.  The fix was adding `-fPIC` at the end of each of the CFLAGS in the x264 Makefile.  Then I had to run `make distclean` for both x264 and ffmpeg and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

In addirion to the good answers here, specifically Robert Lujo's.

I want to say in my case I've been deliberately trying to statically compile a version of ffmpeg. All the required dependencies and what else heretofore required, I've done static compilation.

When I ran `./configure` for the ffmpeg process I didnt notice `--enable-shared` was on the commandline. Removing it and running `./configure` is only then I was able to compile correctly (All 56 mbs of an ffmpeg binary). Check that out as well if your intention is static compilation

Answer (score 0):

I'm building ffmpeg 5.1.2 on CentOS7 with gcc4.8.5.

As mentioned in **${ffmpegRoot}/doc/platform.texi**:

1)configure with option

> **"--enable-pic"**

2)add the following option to your project LDFLAGS

> **"-Wl,-Bsymbolic"**