# Mono installation on RedHat 5.11 (Tikanga)

Tags: mono, redhat

I am trying to install Mono on RedHat 5.11. Here are some details of the mono that we are trying to install.

- **Downloaded from**: http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-3.12.0.tar.bz2
- **Mono version**: 3.12

**Steps to install it:**

1. `./configure --prefix=/opt/mono`
2. `make && make install`

We could install it on CentOS but installing it on RedHat is creating the following issue:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libmini.a(libmini_la-mini.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32     against `mono_cross_helpers_run' can not be used when making a shared object;   recompile with -fPIC 
  /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value 
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I searched around and found the following link: [how to recompile with -fPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812185/how-to-recompile-with-fpic)

To solve this issue I tried running it with `-fPIC` option, but then I realized that the `-fPIC` option does not work with RedHat so I used the `-pie` option. I then performed the following steps:

1. `./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/opt/mono`
2. `make -pie`
3. `make install`

But I still have the same issue:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libmini.a(libmini_la-mini.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against `mono_cross_helpers_run' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

I also see below error on the console

```
make[7]: [cs-errors.tree] Error 1 (ignored)
make[7]: [ecma334.tree] Error 1 (ignored)
make[7]: [Mono.tree] Error 1 (ignored)
make[7]: [netdocs.tree] Error 1 (ignored)
make[7]: [Novell.tree] Error 1 (ignored)
make[8]: *** No rule to make target `../../class/lib/build/sn.exe', needed   by `../../class/lib/xbuild_12/Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll'.  Stop.
make[7]: [do-all] Error 2 (ignored)
make[8]: *** No rule to make target `../../class/lib/build/sn.exe', needed  by `../../class/lib/xbuild_12/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v12.0.dll'.  Stop.
make[7]: [do-all] Error 2 (ignored)
make[8]: *** No rule to make target `../../class/lib/build/sn.exe', needed by `../../class/lib/xbuild_12/Microsoft.Build.Engine.dll'.  Stop.
make[7]: [do-all] Error 2 (ignored)
make[8]: *** No rule to make target `../../class/lib/build/sn.exe', needed by `../../class/lib/xbuild_12/Mono.XBuild.Tasks.dll'.  Stop.
make[7]: [do-all] Error 2 (ignored)
make[8]: *** No rule to make target `../../class/lib/build/sn.exe', needed by `../../class/lib/xbuild_12/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll'.  Stop.
make[7]: [do-all] Error 2 (ignored)
make[8]: *** No rule to make target `../../class/lib/build/sn.exe', needed by `../../class/lib/xbuild_12/Microsoft.Build.dll'.  Stop.
make[7]: [do-all] Error 2 (ignored)
/bin/sh: .//mkinstalldirs: No such file or directory
make[7]: [../../class/lib/xbuild_12//.stamp] Error 127 (ignored)
touch: cannot touch `../../class/lib/xbuild_12//.stamp': No such file or directory
make[7]: [../../class/lib/xbuild_12//.stamp] Error 1 (ignored)
make[7]: [../../class/lib/xbuild_12/xbuild.exe] Error 1 (ignored)
Makefile:821: warning: overriding commands for target `mod'
Makefile:801: warning: ignoring old commands for target `mod'
make[3]: [AgilityPack.dll] Error 1 (ignored)
make[3]: [AgilityPack.dll] Error 1 (ignored)
make[3]: [convert.exe] Error 1 (ignored)
make[3]: [mono-file-formats.tree] Error 1 (ignored)
make[3]: [mono-tools.tree] Error 1 (ignored)
make[3]: [monoapi.tree] Error 1 (ignored)
```

Comment: I also see follwing errors in the log:

Comment: When Xamarin offers .rpm packages, I see no reason to build on your own from source.

Comment: Could you please point me to the rpm for mono-3.12 for RedHat 5.11? That would be really great help.

Comment: The instruction is at Mono web site, http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/

Comment: Hi Lex,                                                                                                           I really appreciate you for replying .We were able to install it on CenOS. The problem we are facing is on RHEL 5.11. Also googling around I found that there's a bug posted which points to the similar problem. Here's a link https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26939#c1