# Recompile with -fPIC Gentoo

Tags: cmake, gentoo, fpic

I'm new to Gentoo and trying to install a 3D modelling program called TexGen (http://texgen.sourceforge.net/index.php/Main_Page) using CMake, and I keep getting the error:

```
relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

This occurs during the step:

```
[ 80%] Linking CXX shared module ../_Renderer.so
```

I've looked all over and tried setting the -fPIC flag in the cmake options file, but there's no change in the result. As I said I'm quite new (in the order of a few weeks) to Linux and Gentoo and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you've only been using linux for a few weeks yet you've delved straight into gentoo? oh boy.

Comment: @MitchWeaver the lab I'm working at only uses gentoo so it's an adventure

Comment: If you're getting this error from an official package I'd suggest you to report it to bugs.gentoo.org, if not then forums.gentoo.org, which is a better equipped platform for novices.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Gentoo has a eclass(es) to build CMake based projects (see `/usr/portage/cmake*.eclass`). And AFAIK, it replace package options with yours (to be precise, it adds a new configuration type), configured in `/etc/portage/make.conf` (or `/etc/paludis/bashrc` if you use [paludis](http://paludis.exherbo.org)). So, I not wondered that "hacking" `CMakeLists.txt` in the package ebuild do not help.

So, easiest way is to add that option to your Gentoo settings instead. Personaly I use [this way](https://github.com/zaufi/paludis-config/blob/master/env.conf.d/add-fpic.conf) to build [`boost`](https://github.com/zaufi/paludis-config/blob/master/package_env.conf#L16) library in my system (yep, I need boost's static libraries to be linked into dynamic one in some of my projects). And yes, I'm using `paludis`, but `emerge` probably has similar feature (a way to set per package compiler options).

The other way, instead of "hacking" compiler options directly (via `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS`), take a look to [CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE.html) -- it'll add a proper compiler option for you, and probably eclass' manipulations with cache wouldn't affect this setting.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work (for installing ffmpeg) by simply reinstalling the whole thing from the beginning with all instances of `$ ./configure` replaced by `$ ./configure --enable-shared` (first make sure to delete all the folders and files including the .so files from the previous attempt).

Apparently this works because https://stackoverflow.com/a/13812368/10593190.