# error in installing opencv 3.3.0

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, installation

I'm trying to install OpenCV 3.3.0 based on these instructions:
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/
But I faced errors while running :

```
sudo cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
           -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local     
           -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON   
           -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF      
           -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules 
           -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python     
           -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

Here's my output in CLI:
[image: CLI Output]

A few minutes ago my cmake command was working properly but I had errors in `make -j4` command which was:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavformat.a(allformats.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `ff_aac_demuxer' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libavformat.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/build.make:312: recipe for target 'lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.3.0' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.3.0] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4918: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

But After I ran my cmake command with `fPIC` It started to show errors on cmake.The command I executed for `fPIC` option:

```
sudo cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
 -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
 -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
 -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
 -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules \
 -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python \
 -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
 -D COMPILE_FLAGS+=-fPIC ..
```

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to install openCV with python3 as interface.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if you have two different files named `libavformat.a` in `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. Also was the error same when you compiled with the flag `-fPIC`

Comment: Line "Configuring incomplete. Error occured!" means that the error has been occured **before**. Show exact error message (as text). BTW, `COMPILER_FLAGS+=fPIC` is wrong syntax for CMake.

Comment: @lakshyaKejriwal It seems that I don't have this path:`/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.Compiling with `-fPIC` showes these 2 lines:`-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/navid/opencv-3.3.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/navid/opencv-3.3.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".`

Comment: @Tsyvarev Here's my complete output:https://pastebin.com/VehVjVED. I can't understand what you mean by error message?Are you asking for the content of CMakeError.log?

Comment: In all probability you have two different `libavformat.a`. Try to locate them using the command `locate -i libavformat.a`

Comment: @LakshyaKejriwal,The locations are:`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.a` and `/usr/local/lib/libavformat.a`

Comment: Try removing the file in `/usr/local/lib/` and create a copy of it in some other location.

Comment: @LakshyaKejriwal,what do you mean by some other location?Where am I supposed to copy that file and why?

Comment: @LakshyaKejriwal,I removed `libavformata` and copied it in my home.However the situation is still the same as before!

Comment: Try compiling it without `-fPIC` now and if there is an error then what is it?

Comment: @LakshyaKejriwal,You can find complete output here:https://pastebin.com/1Vmvn0Cw. Here's my `CMakeError.log`:https://pastebin.com/Hs1SMDmJ

Comment: Did you install `libv4l-dev`?

Comment: @LakshyaKejriwal,`libv4l-dev is already the newest version (1.10.0-1)`. I think there might be some unmet dependencies due I used to get errors in compiling videoio as I copied the error above.

Comment: Try passing the parameter `-D WITH_LIBV4L=OFF` to cmake along with other parameters

Comment: @LakshyaKejriwal,No change.`sudo cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE  -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local  -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON  -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF  -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules  -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python  -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_LIBV4L=OFF ..`

Comment: The **first error message** in the CMake log is `CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:305 (message):`. But even before it strange things are happens: `The imported target "vtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets" references the file` ... `but this file does not exist.`. Looks like your library installation is broken.

Comment: @Tsyvarev,I checked what you said.It's searching for `/home/navid/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules` while I have installed 3.3.0 version.How should I change that so it can find `/home/navid/opencv_contrib-3.3.0/modules`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev,I renamed that file and now cmake is completed successfully but when I run `make -j4`  the error i mentioned above is shown. :(

Comment: `the error i mentioned above is shown.` - Is this error about "recompile with -fPIC"? If so, the error means that `libavformat` library should be compiled with shared libraries, not OpenCV one. See that SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812185/how-to-recompile-with-fpic.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, unfortunately I'm unfamiliar with compiling and other stuff.How should I do that?

Comment: You have found instructions for compile OpenCV, probably by googling them. What is wrong in google the same for `libaformat` library?

Comment: I googled but I didn't found much things about compiling `libavformat` with shared libs. Besides, I tried cmake with `-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` and it was done successfully but I got errors in `make` again.