# Where to put --enable-shared in QtCreator?

Tags: qt-creator

When compiling a qbs project in QtCreator, I get a lot of these errors:
**...requires dynamic R_X86_64_32 reloc which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC**

So, like suggested here [How to recompile with -fPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812185/how-to-recompile-with-fpic) I want to add **--enable-shared** to **./configure** options.
Please tell me where in QtCreator UI I have to put that.

Comment: I tried adding LDFLAGS=-fPIC in the Makefile but it had no effect. Creating "configure" in the root folder of the current project and then just putting "--enable-shared" in also seems wrong - I tried it but got new errors in addition to "...recompile with -fPIC"