# How to fritzing on Linux

Tags: c++, qt5

Following this guide:

https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-app/wiki/1.3-Linux-notes

I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/fritzing/fritzing-app/../libgit2/build/libgit2.a(xprepare.c.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.Release:1091: recipe for target 'Fritzing' failed
make[1]: *** [Fritzing] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/fritzing/fritzing-app'
Makefile:42: recipe for target 'release' failed
make: *** [release] Error 2
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ qmake --version
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.14.2 in /home/jeremy/Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/gcc_64/lib
```

I have not done C++ in a while so I am not familiar with this error.

Comment: `recompile with -fPIC` This may help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812185/how-to-recompile-with-fpic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812185/how-to-recompile-with-fpic)

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same issue and managed to build after many failed attempts.

For the record, I am following the [Fritzing wiki](https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-app/wiki/1.-Building-Fritzing) (recommend to start from there, if you are trying to build for the first time).

Downloaded the Fritzing source code from [GitHub](https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-app) and checked out the 0.9.6 tag/branch.

Running this on Ubuntu 20.04 with QT5 and gcc 9.3.0.

**WHAT WORKED**

Build using `libgit2` dynamic library contrary to what suggested in the wiki and doc.

Skip the [this](https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-app/wiki/1.-Building-Fritzing#libgit2).

Go to the `phoenix.pro` file and set `LIBGIT_STATIC = false`.

Make sure that you have the `libgit2` package installed by running:

```
sudo apt install libgit2-dev
```

The build works.

**WHAT DID NOT WORK**

I could not find the `./configure` command/file and recompile using the `-fPIC` option.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to install using apt (or any application installer that the operating uses i.e. yum install etc)

```
sudo apt install fritzing
```

and to run

```
fritzing
```