# Creating a shared library with existing static library

Tags: cmake

I want to create a shared library with 'sqlite3(SHARED)' and 'glog(STATIC)' installed.

```
add_library(sqlite3 SHARED IMPORTED)
add_library(glog STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(sqlite3 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so)
set_target_properties(glog PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/local/lib/libglog.a)

add_library(${MY_LIBRARY} SHARED ${MY_SOURCE})
target_link_libraries(${MY_LIBRARY} sqlite3 glog)
```

This causes following error

```
/usr/local/lib/libglog.a: can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

What is wrong in CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't with CMake (though you should *never* have hardcoded paths... use `find_package` or `find_library`), it's that you're trying to do something impossible. As your compiler tells you,

> ```
> /usr/local/lib/libglog.a: can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
> ```

`libglog.a` was not compiled with position-independent code, so it *cannot* be used in a shared library, period. There's more information here on SO: [How to recompile with -fPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812185/how-to-recompile-with-fpic)

You'll need to recompile `libglog.a` with `-fPIC`.

Comment: @makepossible99 If this works, please accept the answer (that earns +15 for Alex and +2 for you)